# Accounting System for Winforms / SQL Server applications

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, accounting

If you were going to write a vertical market C# / WinForms / SQL Server application and needed an accounting "engine" for it, what software package would you chose ?

By vertical market, I mean the application is intended to solve a particular set of business problems, not be a generic accounting application. Thus the value add of the program is the 70% of non-accounting related functionality present in the finished product. The 30% of accounting functionality is merely to enable the basic accounting needs of the business.

I said all that to lead up to this:  The accounting engine needs to be a royalty-free runtime license and not super expensive.  I've found a couple C#/SQL Server accounting apps that can be had with source code and a royalty free run time for $150k+ and that would be fine for greenfield development funded by a large bankroll, but for smaller apps, that sort of capital outlay isn't feasible.  Something along the lines of $5k to $15k for a royalty-free runtime would be more reasonable.  Open-source would be even better.

By accounting engine, I mean something that takes care of at a minimum:

- General
- Ledger
- Invoices
- Statements
- Accounts Receivable
- Payments / Credits

Basically, an accounting engine should be something that lets the developer concentrate on the value added (industry specific business best practices / processes) part of the solution and not have to worry about how to implement the low level details of a double entry accounting system.

Ideally, the accounting engine would be something that is licensed on a royalty free run-time basis.

Suggestions, please ?

Answer (score 2):

@Craig  I know this may not be an exact answer to your question, but honestly what your asking for is not that complex to develop.   Double entry book keeping is of itself a pretty simplistic data transformation model.   All you need is a table with accounts, and tables for journals and ledgers.  Writing code to move entries between those tables would take a couple days at most to write and test.   In my experience, most accounting systems are prime markets since most business core operations rely on them, and so they will be expensive. I would recommend hiring someone on contract to write the core functionality if you are unable to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one suggestion:  `www.objacct.com`

Comment: What is objacct about Randy? The link is dead.

Comment: ObjAcct has been purchased by Kaseya maybe two years ago.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Dynamics GP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_GP) comes to mind.
I have not heard of anyone licensing it for repackaging, but 
I know you can adapt it and extend it for different markets.

It might fit your need of allowing the developers to concentrate
on the value ad.

It might be a bit heavy for your needs though.
I mention it since a lot of my clients are using it.

Another option which might be closer to your needs is 
[AdaptAccounts](http://www.adapta.com/.net-accounting-software.htm)

Comment: I think @ $2500 a user, Microsoft Dynamics GP isn't what I'm looking for.  I need something that can be purchased (or is open source) and integrated into products without having to count users.  I'm updating the parent post to include the need for a royalty-free runtime license.

Answer (score 0):

One that is excellent and of good reputation around the globe is [Sage Software Accpac](http://www.sageaccpac.com/)

The Sage Accpac ERP's SDK makes it simple to integrate via COM objects, and is working on different DBRM engines such as Pervasive SQL and SQL Server, just to name these two.

Plus, you may choose what module you buy for your company's needs. Now, it all depends on your budget as it is a commercial solution that is renown to be a little expensive, but definately reliable and stable.

Comment: This isn't for -my- company's needs, it is for integration into a vertical market app to be sold.  I've updated my parent post for this if you are still interested in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

TRAVERSE from Open Systems, Inc. may be an option. .net,SQL,C# Accounting and Business software. Integrates easily with third party verticals.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked around in the past for this type of thing and have always came to the conclusion of using a commercial accounting package and doing as much integration as possible. There are several reasons for this including:

1. With a common commercial accounting package, you can usually find someone who is able to use it without much effort and/or cost of training.
2. If your vertical app is built to integrate with an external accounting app, and it is successfull, you can build integration to additional packages that potential customers may already have in place.
3. Generally, external accountants (CPAs) for most companies like to be able to know that the accounting application that their client is using is well known and supported. There are a lot of reasons for this including cost savings on doing annual tasks (such as corporate taxes).  With a common application, the CPA often can request very specific reports/info that already exist.

There are many more advantages, but I am sure you get the picture.

Depending on the needs of you clients in terms of accounting, you can start as basic as QuickBooks and go up from there.  There is always someone around that knows how to work within QuickBooks and it has a decent integration API.  From there you can step up to many of the Sage solutions and/or Microsoft solutions as they are very common and widely used.

I know that you stated that you want and API/Engine to build on, but I would highly suggest considering the integration option with a standard commercial package.

Comment: Hmm...Guess I need to look at the date closer before I answer.  I just saw this in the unaswered list and had some thoughts.  After typing up my answer, I notices the date. :(

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, but that doesn't work for me. I would be at a disadvantage to my competitors if I required my users to purchase a copy of Quickbooks in order to use my software.

Answer (score -1):

Check XERP.Net @ http://xerpdotnet.codeplex.com , It looks promising (It's free but rely on XAF which will cost you 2,000$ per developer initially and around 800$ a year later and you will get a fully loaded DevExpress tools anyways).

Comment: Does not look promising at all. Please look at the FAQ. Q. Who owns the code? A. You own the code as long as you help us to develop XERP. What after XERP is developed?